# where can I host my .flac(audio) files? cheaply

Tags: google-drive

I'm working on a project where I need audio files. I have audio files folder around 500 MB with 5K audio files. I was thinking if I can host these files on Google drive or Mediafire and then use them in my web app(which will use the audio files(from the folder) and another audio file that I will upload to do some analysis).

I uploaded my files to google drive and Mediafire.

On Google drive: I shared the folder and I was expecting that I can access file using **SHARED-URL/xyz.flac**, But this was not the case every time I try to access **SHARED-URL/xyz.flac**, It takes me to the folder. There is an option I can individually share the files. But each file will have its own URL. I was hoping I could have something like **ONE_SINGLE_URL/xyz.flac** for 5K files.

However, I can have **ONE_SINGLE_URL/xyz.flac** on Mediafire. but that's not a downloadable link. It takes you to the page you can actually download the file.

I don't want to use any paid service for that, so using something like S3 is not an option.

Suggestions are welcome. Please let me know If more Info is required on the Question.